# Keeping an image view out of scrollview scope. Xcode, Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode9

Please take a look at an image below
[image]
There is a scroll view. But I don't want an imageView(topBar) move. How can I keep an image view out of scrollview scope? (I mean fixed topBar, no move) With a constraint? And managing the constraint from code behind during the scroll?

Answer (score 0):

Move the top bar image so that it isn't in the scrollview. It's parent should be the `View0 Outlet`, then you can constrain it however you want without it moving in then scrollview.

Comment: I move the topBar image view between View0Outlet and the Safe Area. But this time i can't see this topBar image. Because it went back. @Clever Error Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using a stackView with vertical setting and free form. In this case, you can lock the height of topBar.

[image]

Comment: Dear @E.Coms, height of the page is 967 points. topBar's height is 174 points. What is height size for vertical stack view should be? 174 or 967 points? Thanks

Comment: You don't need to set height of stackView. you just lock the four edges with superView. I set topBar 150, you can set it 174.